# Передача в __global__ функцию массива

Tags: c++, cuda

К примеру есть такой код:

```cpp
#include <cuda.h>                                                           
#include <iostream>                                                         

struct Matrix {
  int mat[9];                                                               
};                                                                          

__global__ void kernel(Matrix mat, int *out) {                              
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    *out += mat.mat[i];
  }
}

int main() {
  int *out = nullptr;                                                       
  cudaMalloc(&out, sizeof(int));                                            

  Matrix matrix{};                                                          
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {                                             
    matrix.mat[i] = 1;                                                      
  }
   kernel<<<1, 1>>>(matrix, out);                                            

   int retval;                                                               
   cudaMemcpy(&retval, out, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);            

   std::cout << retval << std::endl;                                         

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                      
 }
```

При этом код работает и выводит верный результат, в связи с чем возникает вопрос: насколько он корректен? С одной стороны мы можем разыменовывать указатели на `cpu` память в `cuda` функциях, однако массив на стэке иммет другой тип (хотя и автоматически приводится к указателю).

Comment: Что за чушь? Если массив "завернут" в класс, то такой массив будет прекрасно копироваться вместе с классом. Не нужно никакого `memcpy` или цикла.

Comment: @AnT возможно - никогда не пользовался подобным внутри классов. Тем не менее это относится только к PS (который будет удален), вопрос же это не снимает